# Show deepest todo in sub-tree

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Can I configure the org-todo-list to show only the most nested TODOs in a subtree?

The reasoning is to always see what's the next step on a project, without cluttering with all the parent items

For example:

```
# file.txt
* TODO A
* TODO B
** TODO C
** TODO D
*** DONE E
*** TODO F
*** TODO G
```

What shows up in org-todo-list today:

```
file: TODO A
file: TODO B
file: TODO C
file: TODO D
file: TODO F
file: TODO G
```

What I'd like to see:

```
file: TODO A
file: TODO C
file: TODO F
file: TODO G
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: org calls this type of functionality "Sparse trees", but I'm not sure that this particular type of sparse tree is implemented in org itself.  So I think you'd have to either find somebody who's implemented that already as add-on code (I had a quick search and couldn't find that), or implement it yourself with some elisp... or wait for somebody to show up here and implement it for you ;-)